# Sorting array in Computed property in Vue.JS is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently practicing in Vue.js and I have encountered a problem regarding the sorting of arrays in Vue.js. The sort(a-b) should perform an ascending order which is the least alphabet/value first but the array is still the same. There is no changes of order. I have a function inside the computed property and it doesn't work. I am stucked here for hours now. Here is my code below,

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar/>
    <div class="container p-4">
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1><br />
      <br>
      <Button/>
      <Table :people="sortedPeople"/>
    </div>
    <Modal @submit="submitPerson" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue'
  import Button from './components/Button'
  import Table from './components/Table.vue'
  import Modal from './components/Modal.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    data(){
      return {
        title: 'People',
        name:'Rename This',
        people: [
          {
            fname: 'Ab',
            lname: 'Zigzag'
          },
          {
            fname: 'Al',
            lname: 'Alabasta'
          }
        ],
      }
    },
    components: { Button, Navbar, Table, Modal },
    computed:{
      sortedPeople(){
        return this.people.sort((a, b) => a.lname - b.lname)
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submitPerson(person) {
        if(person.first_name && person.last_name) {
          this.people.push({ fname: person.first_name, lname: person.last_name })
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here is my table component,

```
<template>
    <table class="table table-sm table-responsive table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Names</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody v-for="(person, i) in people">
            <tr>
                <td>{{  i+=1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ person.fname+" "+person.lname }}</td>
                <td>{{ Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) }}/100</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "Table",
        props: { people: Array },
    }
</script>
```

What is the correct way of using computed property? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To sort an array of strings in JavaScript, you should use the localeCompare method:

```
computed: {
  sortedPeople() {
    return this.people.slice().sort((a, b) => a.lname.localeCompare(b.lname));
  }
}
```

When comparing strings with sort, the subtraction operation `a.lname - b.lname` will result in NaN

Also, note the use of `slice()`. Without `slice()`, the sort method would sort the people array in place, modifying the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare strings, i.e. `sort((a, b) => a.lname.localeCompare(b.lname))`

Answer (score 1):

You can check all conditions normally in your comparator function.

```
this.people.sort((a,b) => {
  if (a.lname < b.lname) return -1
  if (a.lname > b.lname) return 1
  return 0
});
```

Comment: Nice! It works too